# How to specify a variable as an argument?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to Java, I have been instructed to carry out the following:

- Create a new class `Food`
- The name of the food specified as an argument.
- A getter method for the name of the food.

My attempt looks like:

```
public class Food 
{
    String food;    

    Food() {
        food = "";
    }
    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }
}
```

Would I the name of food be specified as an argument be changed to:

```
Food(String food) {
    food = "";
}
```

Or any different way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you have to assign the argument to a field where you store the name of the food. This is the code with the explanation in comments.

```
//class Food
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    private String name; 

    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    //getter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, then make sure to use the argument in the body:

```
Food(String food) {
    // need `this` to refer to instance variable food since there's 
    // scope overlap.
    this.food = food;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class Food {


    String food;    

    Food()   
    {

    }

        public String getFood()
    {

        return food;

    }



    public void setFood(String food)   


     {

         //this is used as to set the value that you passed from your main class     throught your object

            this.food = food;
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Food object=new Food();
            object.setFood("Apple");
          String name= object.getFood();

            System.out.print(name);

        }

    }
```